# Publish WinForms App with WebAssembly Blazor for Local Use

Tags: c#, winforms, blazor, publish, blazor-webassembly

I need to create a .exe file for my WinForms App that works with my web page developed with Blazor. Everything is in the same project.

If I start my project on VS2019 it will run the web and then it'll start the WinForms.
Everything works fine. But if I try to publish, the WinForms no longer opens and it seems that the Web part doesn't start at all.

The WinForms App will be working on a VM and the WebSite will be available for me locally at this momment.

I use Xampp to manage my DB.

What I have tried:

- Publish both projects separately using the publish page on VS;
- Publish the project as one using the publish page on VS;
- I know how to create a single .exe file for a winForms app, so I set the configs on the .csproj
  file and tried that too, but .exe file created does not start at all;
- I've set try/catch blocks at the beggining of the application so that maybe I could see the
  exception, but again, nothing happens, the loading cursor appears then stops.

This is my Project Structure:

[image: projectStructure]

Comment: I always regarded Blazor as adequate for replacing WinForms to a big degree; what kind of interaction between the two are you seeking?

Comment: The VM will be using the winForms app to read a List and start processes, the website will be inserting processes in this list.